# Display each element of a list in a separate line in an Angular2 component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an Angular2 component to display the list of speakers in some data. When I put the following code in my `xyz.component.html`, it displays the list as comma separated strings. How can I display each one in a different line -- essentially put a line break after every one.

```
<div *ngIf="data.speakers">
    <span class="attr-key">Speakers:</span><br>
    <span class="attr-value">{{data.speakers}}</span>
</div>
```

`data` is what comes due to binding. It has an element called speakers that is defined as `string[]`.

Comment: can you list your data.speakers you need to use `ngFor` instead of `ngIf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **`ngFor`** to loop over data and display it

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let speaker of data.speakers">
      {{ speaker}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how do u know about the data ? atleast wait for the data :P

Comment: he is not quite sure of it i guess that is why i posted the comment